# statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing: what do “additive”/“multiplicative” trend and seasonality actually mean?

Tags: time-series, statistics, statsmodels

There are additional concepts of **additivity** and **multiplicativity** for

- **trend** (`trend{“add”, “mul”, “additive”, “multiplicative”, None}`) and
- **seasonality** (`seasonal{“add”, “mul”, “additive”, “multiplicative”, None}`)

in the **[Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html)** implementation [1, 2] of the **Triple Exponential Smoothing (Holt-Winter's Method)**.

Actually, this means different methods of calculating the **initializing** values ​​of seasonality and trend correspondingly (according to [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters/model.py#L1256)):

```py
m = self.seasonal_periods
l0 = initial_level
b0 = initial_trend
if has_seasonal:
    l0 = y[np.arange(self.nobs) % m == 0].mean() if l0 is None else l0
    if b0 is None and has_trend:
        # TODO: Fix for short m
        lead, lag = y[m : m + m], y[:m]
        if trend == "mul":
            b0 = np.exp((np.log(lead.mean()) - np.log(lag.mean())) / m)
        else:
            b0 = ((lead - lag) / m).mean()
    s0 = list(y[:m] / l0) if seasonal == "mul" else list(y[:m] - l0)
elif has_trend:
    l0 = y[0] if l0 is None else l0
    if b0 is None:
        b0 = y[1] / y[0] if trend == "mul" else y[1] - y[0]
    s0 = []
else:
    if l0 is None:
        l0 = y[0]
    b0 = None
    s0 = []
```

In other words, when there *is seasonality*

- the initial *additive* trend will be:

$$ b_0 = \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{i=0} \frac{y_{i+m} - y_i}{m}$$

- the initial *multiplicative* trend will be:

$$ b_0 = \frac{ \ln \left( {\frac{1}{m}\sum^{m}_{i=0}y_{i+m}} \right) - \ln \left({\frac{1}{m}\sum^{m}_{i=0}y_{i}} \right)}{m} $$

where $m$ is the length of the one period, and $\mathbf{y}$ is the input vector (time series).

When there *is no seasonality*

- the initial *additive* trend will be:

$$ b_0 = y_1 - y_0 $$

- the initial *multiplicative* level will be:

$$ \ln(b_0) = \ln(y_1) - \ln(y_0) $$

The zero value of the seasonality (zero period) for its additive or multiplicative form is defined as the difference or ratio between the first m samples and the zero value of the level, respectively.

AND this is NEITHER a classical additive/multiplicative [decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-decomposition.html) or additive/multiplicative [Exponential smoothing](https://otexts.com/fpp2/taxonomy.html) as I understand. Moreover, trend and seasonality can be additive or multiplicative independently of each other in Statsmodels.

So, the questions:

1. **Does somebody have got any reference about the right selection of the values of the parameters?**
2. **Can anybody explain for what cases these parameters should be used?**

I'll be appreciated your replies!

**References**:

1. [Statsmodels.Tsa.Holtwinters.Exponentialsmoothing — Statsmodels.](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html)
2. [GitHub. 2020. Statsmodels/Statsmodels.](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters/model.py)

Comment: I was researching a little about it and find this [reference](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=gcspLg1fR7EC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=Multiplicative+Trend&source=bl&ots=VsHq4mvo7V&sig=ACfU3U15-7ndp1a_1LwyV0JlnzACwO72-A&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjakIC_9Z7wAhW3D7kGHcHKDt8Q6AEwEHoECBEQAw#v=onepage&q=Multiplicative%20Trend&f=false). Perhaps it could help you.